# Xero Node OAuth Authorise Callback URL not working after Allowing Access

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, xero-api

Upon using the `xero-node` library to generate a Request Token via the `getRequestToken` function the given URL does not redirect the user to the callback address that was specified in the config.

Instead a screen with a code is shown for manual entering. I have also specified the callback domain in the app settings in the Xero Developer Centre "My Apps" section .

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add your callback url to your config file in a field called `authorizeCallbackUrl`.

This is what causes the automatic redirect to occur.

Check the readme in the repo for an example.